# Is there a way to add each element of a pair of objects automatically in node.js?

Tags: node.js, object

Let's say I have two objects.

```
obj1 = {
    a: 1,
    b: 3,
    c: 1
}

obj2 = {
    a: 3,
    b: 1,
    c: 3
}
```

And I would like to add these two. In a way that each key value add them together with the corresponding one. So obj3 = obj1 + obj2 would result in:

```
obj3 = {
    a: 4,
    b: 4,
    c: 4
}
```

Is there a simpler way of doing this without manually adding each key value pair like

```
obj3.a = obj1.a + obj2.a
```

Comment: Just use a `for .. in` loop

Answer (score 0):

This is something that could be done very simply through the use of `Array.prototype.reduce()` if you were able to store these objects as an array:

```js
  const myObjects = [
    {
      a: 1,
      b: 3,
      c: 1,
    },
    {
      a: 3,
      b: 1,
      c: 3,
    },
  ];

  const output = myObjects.reduce((prev, curr) => ({
    a: prev.a + curr.a,
    b: prev.b + curr.b,
    c: prev.c + curr.c,
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

This function sum property's object (dynamic property)

```js
function objSumProperty(obj1, obj2) {
    const data = {};

    Object.keys(obj1).map((k) => (data[k] = obj1[k] + (obj2[k] || 0)));

  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parameters rest (`...`) to collect all objects to an array. Create an array of all entries (`[key, value]` pairs) using `Array.flatMap()` with `Object.entries()`. Reduce the array of entries to a single object.

This function allows you to combine all keys from 2 or more objects, even if the objects have different keys.

```js
const fn = (...objs) => objs
  .flatMap(Object.entries)
  .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({
    ...acc, 
    [key]: (acc[key] ?? 0) + value
  }), {})
  

const obj1 = {"a":1,"b":3,"c":1}
const obj2 = {"a":3,"b":1,"c":3}

console.log(fn(obj1, obj2)) // combining 2 objects

const obj3 = {"a":10,"d":15,"e":20}

console.log(fn(obj1, obj2, obj3)) // combining 3 objects
```